# Reduce carbon dioxide in the atmosphere

Tags: pressure

Can carbon dioxide in the atmosphere be reduced by burying dry ice or pressurized CO2 in airtight containers?

Comment: It depends from where the energy for the process is taken.

Answer (score 1):

This carbon dioxide that is being buried would have to first be extracted from the atmosphere to lower the amount in the atmosphere. This happened quite significantly during the formation of the Himalayas and other mountain ranges (the net effect is still being [studied](https://wheatoncollege.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/GaillardetGaly-CO2SciencePerspect-Science-2008.pdf)). There are very interesting technologies (called [carbon sequestration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_sequestration) and "carbon capture") being tested that would do something similar to what you are talking about except probably in a more inert solid form (e.g., [biochar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochar)). Otherwise the best bet is probably just planting more trees, although this is a controversial [topic](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/366/6463/316.2).

Comment: Carbon sequestration in the form of atmospheric CO2 extraction will result in a LOT of CO2.  From the chemistry involved, for every 16 kg of methane burned, you get 44 kg of CO2.  Pumping and sequestering the volumes of CO2 required to appreciably affect atmospheric CO2 emissions is a non-trivial challenge.